Material UI: DataGrid server-side pagination flickering data when using swr
I want to display server-side paginated data on a Material UI DataGrid with data fetched using swr. I've been working through MUI's introduction example for server side data in DataGrid which is using the useEffect hook to fetch data but I have adapted it for swr Here are the relevant parts of my code
const [paginationModel, setPaginationModel] = useState({
  page: 0,
  pageSize: 3,
});

const fetcher = (url: RequestInfo) => fetch(url).then((res) => res.json());

const { data, error, isLoading, mutate } = useSWR(
    `http://localhost:3002/ingredients/pagination?page=${paginationModel.page}&pageSize=${paginationModel.pageSize}`,
    fetcher
  );

const rowCountRef = useRef(data?.rowCount || 0);

const rowCount = useMemo(() => {
  if (data?.rowCount !== undefined) {
    rowCountRef.current = data.rowCount;
  }
  return rowCountRef.current;
}, [data?.rowCount]);

return (
  <Box sx={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
    <DataGrid
      rows={data?.data ?? []}
      rowCount={rowCount}
      columns={columns}
      loading={loading}
      initialState={{
        pagination: {
          paginationModel: {
            pageSize: 5,
          },
        },
      }}
      pageSizeOptions={[3, 5, 10, 50]}
      disableRowSelectionOnClick
      pagination
      paginationMode="server"
      paginationModel={paginationModel}
      onPaginationModelChange={setPaginationModel}
    />
    <Button onClick={buttonHandler}>Post</Button>
  </Box>
);

My pagination endpoint returns json that contains a data field containing the ingredient elements and a rowCount field containing the total number of rows.
What I have currently mostly works but I am seeing flickering total rows as well as rows data under certain conditions.
The problem scenario occurs under these conditions

Paginate through a couple of pages to "cache" those pages.
Add a new record.
Switch to a different page in the table that you have already visited and total is seen momentarily displaying the old value before updating to its new value (should be +1 since a new record was added). This will happen at every page you have already visited. If the rows on one of those cached pages have changed, it will also display the old rows until the new data is pulled in from the back end. See short video demonstration of this here

If I instead use React's useEffect hook to do server-side pagination this issue does not seem to happen. When paging to a new page the old rowCount is displayed until the network request returns with the new total count and rowCount is updated accordingly. Visiting subsequent pages after that does not suffer from any of the flickering that is seen when using swr
I would assume this is related to a caching issue but I am unable to wrap my head around what specifically is going on. I find it strange that with each "cached" page in the table the rowCount prop holds onto that cached value seemingly specific to each page yet the DataGrid component itself has a singular rowCount prop. I would assume the first time revalidation of data occurs, the latest rowCount value is calculated and subsequent pages would display accurately, however, this is not the case.
Can anyone provide insight on this and is there a more elegant way to handle new data coming in? It feels like bad UX to momentarily display the cached values before the correct data is streamed in.
Link to code sandbox
The code sandbox does not exactly implement the code above since I had to mock the network requests but it is comparably similar. The sandbox implements server-side pagination using both the useEffect hook and swr. To switch between each approach you need to comment/uncomment out the props for rows, rowCount, and loading (lines 97-104)

I don't see any "flickering" of data. What I do see is you add a record to the data which increases the row count total. When you page back to a previous page I see that page data being revalidated once and then the total data row count update once to reflect the current total count.
When I swap over to your useEffect logic I see a loading indicator when switching pages. If this is all you want when using the useSWR hook then I suggest also using the returned isValidating state to display/render the loading UI any time paged data is being loaded and when it is being re-validated.
Example:
const {
  data,
  error,
  isLoading,
  isValidating, // <--
  mutate
} = useSWR(
  `http://localhost:3002/ingredients/pagination?page=${paginationModel.page}&pageSize=${paginationModel.pageSize}`,
  fetcher
);

...

<DataGrid
  rows={data?.data ?? []}
  rowCount={rowCount}
  columns={columns}
  loading={loading || isValidating} // <-- loading or validating
  initialState={{
    pagination: {
      paginationModel: {
        pageSize: 5,
      },
    },
  }}
  pageSizeOptions={[3, 5, 10, 50]}
  disableRowSelectionOnClick
  pagination
  paginationMode="server"
  paginationModel={paginationModel}
  onPaginationModelChange={setPaginationModel}
/>


with respect to the total row count being displayed I'm seeing that with each visited page it is seemingly recalculating the new total when using swr. See this short clip demonstrating that. https://giphy.com/gifs/0LiJgX9PjeZZGtTUxm
I'm not understanding why it is recalculating on each page revisit when we can see on the current page rowCount has already been updated to reflect the new total.

@RipeFruit This seems to be normal behavior when revalidating data after a mutation. You might be able to skirt around this with optimistic updates though. I'm not very familiar with SWR, so there might also be some method to update all cached entries after a mutation.
